# Calculate route with graphhopper based on air quality data

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I am developing a full stack application with java spring boot for the back-end and react for the front-end. The idea behind the app is to be able to select origin and destination location and based on that to get a route between them considering the air quality a.k.a to pick the route with the best air quality data.

So what is the best way to implement route calculation based on air quality. I am using a local instance of graphhoper in the back-end.